# PDO Results to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I moved over from plain MYSQL to PDO MYSQL and started using prepared statements. With my old system I was able to query the database and store the information in a array. I would then use usort to sort the table by money amount.

Since I've moved to PDO I'm having trouble using the array I get out of it. My origional code is as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, item, cash, props FROM Donators";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$result_array = array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $result_array[] = $row;
        //var_dump($result_array);
    }
} else {
    echo "You have yet to join our servers!";
}
$conn->close();

function custom_sort($a,$b) {
    return $a['cash']<$b['cash'];
 }
usort($result_array, "custom_sort");
```

This results in the table being sorted by the column 'cash'. The code below is from my PDO code.

```
    try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name, item, cash, props FROM Donators"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    $result_array = array();
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
       $result_array[$k] = $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

function custom_sort($a,$b) {
    return $a['cash']<$b['cash'];
 }
//print_r($result_array);
usort($result_array, "custom_sort");
$length = count($result_array);
```

usort will cause this error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'cash'
```

Printing the array $result_array shows

```
Array ( [name] => Жэка90 [item] => none [cash] => 1000 [props] => 0 )
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you chose not to do sorting in your query by using `ORDER BY`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the following code:

```
// In case an error occured during statement execution, throw an exception
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
    // Error handling with $stmt->errorInfo()
}

// Fetch all results
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It doesn't need a foreach loop to process the data afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the for loop to

```
foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $k=>$v) {
```

Fixed this.